# Rails - How to specify foreign key explicitly when using :include method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a Rails controller where I'm trying to return a json object that is composed of several associated models derived from a legacy SQL Server Database.  As I'm new to this and experimenting, I'm using ":include" on only one associated model until I can get that to work, and then up the ante.

Controller:

```
class SlotMachineEntityController < ApplicationController
  def retrieveAll
      @blah = Machine.where("Machine.CasinoID = 2").find(1, :select => "Machine.MachineID", :include => :slot_instance)

      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => @blah }
      end
  end
end
```

The error is:

> TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name '**machine_id**'.: ...
>   [Master].[SlotInstance].[Active] AS t1_r10 FROM [Master].[Machine]
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN [Master].[SlotInstance] ON
>   [Master].[SlotInstance].[**machine_id**] = [Master].[Machine].[MachineID]
>   WHERE [Master].[Machine].[MachineID] = @0 AND (Machine.CasinoID = 2)',
>   N'@0 int', @0 = 1

Presumably the error takes place when it tries to execute ":include => :slot_instance" and reverts to the default naming convention by looking for "machine_id" instead of "MachineID" which is the key used in the database.  I cannot find the syntax wherein I specify for the :include method that the foreign key is MachineID and not machine_id.

For reference, the relevant models are:

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "Master.Machine"
    set_primary_key "MachineID"

    has_one :slot_instance
    belongs_to :manufacturer, :foreign_key => "ManufacturerID"
    belongs_to :casino, :foreign_key => "CasinoID"
    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => "CustomerID"
end

class SlotInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "Master.SlotInstance"
    set_primary_key "SlotInstanceID"

    belongs_to :game_configuration, :foreign_key => "GameConfigurationID"
    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => "CustomerID"
    belongs_to :casino, :foreign_key => "CasinoID"
    belongs_to :location, :foreign_key => "LocationID"
    belongs_to :machine, :foreign_key => "MachineID"
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A far as i can see from your piece of code, maybe you coding some API. Believe me, if i were you i would consider something like active_model_serializers to help you out and be more on track as app might grow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the foreign key in the has_one relation in the machine class, i.e.

```
has_one :slot_instance, :foreign_key => "MachineID"
```

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that that only needed to be done for the 'belongs_to' component of associations. So obvious now, but thanks for pointing it out.